# Java Game Mouse Movement

Tags: java, user-interface, mouse, awt, mouseevent

I'm making a game in which we have to use 'Catchers' to catch balls which fall from the top of the window. Catches can only move left/right.

Example: http://puu.sh/xeq8

Which direction should I look/head into if I want to make it so that I can move a 'catcher' with a mouse?

Right now, I have a catcher that uses the keyboard - I used `KeyListener` however I am uncertain for the mouse.

Ideally, I'd like the catcher to move left/right when the mouse moves in the JPanel? Or something of that sort would be ideal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a MouseMotionListener :

```
myPanel.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() { 
   public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) { 
      //move the catcher
      //use me.getX() to have the horizontal position of the mouse
      //eg : catcher.setX(me.getX())
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `MouseMotionListener` to be notified of the position of mouse, I think you also need to click to capture the falling balls for that use `MouseListener` or `MouseAdapter`.

When your clicks your `MouseListener` will be notified and when they move their mouse poistion your `MouseMotionListener` callback will be triggered.

1. [How to work with MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)
2. [How to work with MouseMotionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)